Why is Jest test passing all the test cases skipping user authentication?
Integration test using jest skips user authentication and passes all the test cases for the resolvers in grapql in NestJS.
For resolver in the 'category.resolver.ts':
import { Args, Mutation, Resolver, Query, Context } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from '../auth/guards/jwt-auth.guard';
import { RolesGuard } from '../auth/guards/roles.guard';
import { UserRole } from '@prisma/client';
import { PrivilegesList } from '../privileges/user-privileges';
import { PermissionsGuardOR } from '../auth/guards/permissions-or.guard';
import { Roles } from '../auth/decorators/roles.decorator';
import { Permissions } from '../auth/decorators/permissions.decorator';
import { Category, PaginatedCategory } from './entities/category.entity';

@Resolver()
export class CategoryResolver {
  constructor(public readonly categoryService: CategoryService) {}

  @Mutation(() => Category)
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard, PermissionsGuardOR)
  @Roles(UserRole.SUPERADMIN)
  @Permissions([PrivilegesList.CATEGORY_MANAGEMENT.CAPABILITIES.CREATE])
  createCategory(@Args('name') name: string): Promise<Category> {
    return this.categoryService.createCategory(name);
  }
}

I tried in the test file 'category.resolver.spec.ts':
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CategoryResolver } from './category.resolver';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { PrismaService } from '../prisma/prisma.service';

describe('CategoryResolver', () => {
  let categoryResolver: CategoryResolver;
  let appSetup;
  let createdCategory;
  let updatedCategory;
  let userRole;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [CategoryResolver, CategoryService, PrismaService],
    })
      .compile();

    categoryResolver = module.get<CategoryResolver>(CategoryResolver);
  });

  it('Create category', async () => {
    let createCategoryInput = 'Java';
    createdCategory = await categoryResolver.createCategory(
      createCategoryInput,
    );

    expect(200);
    expect(createdCategory).toHaveProperty(['name']);
  });
}

After running the test:
/app # yarn test category.resolver.spec.ts
yarn run v1.22.22
$ jest category.resolver.spec.ts
PASS src/category/category.resolver.spec.ts (7.958 s)
CategoryResolver
✓ Create category (198 ms)
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.062 s
Ran all test suites matching /category.resolver.spec.ts/i.
Done in 2.49s.

The @UseGuards() decorator will not be taken into account if you call the resolver directly. This is because it doesn't actually modify the method, but rather adds metadata that Nest reads at runtime to set up the request chain for when a request actually passes through the server. Calling the resolver directly bypasses this, so you don't need any authentication in unit tests

Thank you so much @Jay McDoniel.
Could you kindly suggest me how to implement this in Integration test so that @UseGuards() can be taken into account??

You'd need to follow the e2e testing guide in the docs, or check out the testing-nestjs community repository on GitHub
